# Trying to parse out images from CSS but regex breaks when used on compressed CSS files

Tags: php, css, regex

I'm parsing image paths from CSS files for a project I'm working on and the following expression works fine provided the CSS file in question hasn't been compressed/minified.

Here's the expression that I'm using:

```
"/url\((.+)\)./"
```

When I use it with preg_match_all() against CSS such as the inline compressed CSS on Google's homepage it returns on result with the entire inline CSS block.  What am I missing in the expression that's causing this to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a ? after the + to make the match non-greedy: `url\((.+?)\).`

Alternatively, match the character class that just excludes the right paren: `url\(([^)]+)\).`

That second one is actually much faster, btw

Comment: The first suggestion fixed the issue.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The second one is much faster because there will be less backtracking in the matching engine.